# $this->db->_error_number() returning 0 and not the error number

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter not returning the error number

```
 $this->db->trans_start();
 $deal_enquiry = $this->db->insert('deal_enquiry', $data);
 $enquiry_id = $this->db->insert_id();
 $this->db->trans_complete();

 if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
     echo $this->db->_error_number();
     if ($this->db->_error_number() == 0){
        $errormsg="Duplicate entry";
        return $errormsg;      
     } else{
        $errormsg="Enquiry failed";
        return $errormsg;      
     }
     //    return false;
 } else {
     return true;
 }
```

The error number is always returning 0 even if there is an error. When i set the db_debug to true the error number is something different. Why am i not getting the correct error number. Can someone please point out the problem.
Thanks,

Comment: By convention, enything prefixed with _ is a private member. So you're calling a private/protected method which might not have a default implementation or an override. In short, find another way and try to use only public members.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error number by echo $this->db->_error_number(); before the trans_complete();
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

For others experiencing similar issues. Make sure you have Database Debugging enabled in your database.php configuration file.